# What's a good pattern for iOS apps that have a lot of lookup tables?

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns

I've got an application that has a lot of (short) lookup tables (codes -> human readable string), what's the best way to implement looking up these codes in an ObjC/iOS app?

I was thinking a "Lookup" class that has a dictionary (property) for each lookup or maybe something with a plist?

I am wondering how others handle this kind of situation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by a lot. A plist would probably work fine. But if your storing a ton of data, and if you need store anything else associated with the codes, I would look into core data.This looks like a good tutorial on how to do that with a plist: http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/03/read-and-write-data-from-plist-file.html